# How to make this CSS grid work with justify-content?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-grid

I have the following snippet:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 3</li>
  <li>Test 4</li>
  <li>Test 5</li>
</ul>
```

**Actual result:** the elements in the second row of the grid are on the left side of the grid, not on the center axis of the grid.

**Expected result:** the elements in the second row of the grid should be aligned to the horizontal center axis of the grid.

There are no error messages. I have tried doing a few searches on the Internet and on SO.

I have seen [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) and still do not understand why this does not work well. In this page it tells about the *inline axis* of a grid container. I tried searching about this but I could not find anything relevant for me.

I use Firefox.

Thank you.

Comment: That's how CSS-Grid works...you actually want flexbox here. CSS-Grid will place elements *in the grid* depending on the columns you have defined.

Comment: `justify-content:center` on a CSS-Grid container will center all the elements as a "group", not individual elements in the grid. See the demo on MDN